# How to set widget toolbar with 4 buttons after every textview

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm designing a quotes app and i m having so many quotes in one page (activity) so i want a widget toolbar and 4 share buttons after every textview, i did this through xml, i want to do this by coding in java activity so the coding length will reduce, please give me the right solution for this and please look out these pics and my code

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsiDw.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="technoapps4.shayari_vayari.second">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:onClick="tv"
                android:text="@string/Funny1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tb"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/copy1"
                android:onClick="copy1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="08dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/copy" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/whatsapp1"
                android:onClick="whatsapp1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fb1"
                android:onClick="fb1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-46dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/facebook" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/share1"
                android:onClick="share1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="275dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-46dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/share" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/Funny2"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/copy2"
                android:onClick="copy2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="08dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/copy" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/what2"
                android:onClick="whatsapp2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/whatsapp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fb2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                android:onClick="fb2"
                android:layout_marginTop="-46dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/facebook" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/share2"
                android:onClick="share2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="275dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-46dp"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/share" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will have many Quotes to display, I suggest you use `RecyclerView` along with `RecyclerView.Adapter`. `LinearLayout` might slow your app dow.

But if your quotes are not so much, or you are really want to use `LinearLayout`. You can build a `listitem_quote.xml` contains your quote and 4 Buttons first.

And then use an empty `LinearLayout` in your `activity.xml` like this.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```

In your activity, `inflate()` for every quotes. And add them to your layout.

```
onCreate(...){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    for(...){ // for every quote
        // create a view for quote contains buttons
        View quoteView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_quote, null);
        TextView tvQuote = quoteView.findViewById(...);
        tvQuote.setText(...);
        Button btn1 = quoteView.findViewById(...);
        btn1.setOnclickListener(...);
        myLinearLayout.addView(quote);// add to Linearlayout
    }
}
```

This will do the trick.

However I still suggest you to use `RecyclerView` instead.
You can find many examples on the internet.
It looks more complex but it's useful.